# Print grid with setting domLayout

Tags: angular, printing, ag-grid

I'm trying to print a grid but the `setDomLayout()` method is not recognize.
This is my html :

```
<div class="ui-g-12 ui-g-nopad print" [ngStyle]="style">
    ag-grid-angular #grid id="grid-printable"
        style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" 
        class="ag-theme-blue grid-printable"
        (gridReady)="onGridReady(grid)"
        [rowData]="rowData"
        [gridOptions]="gridOptions">
    </ag-grid-angular>
</div>
```

and my ts print function looks like :

```
print(grid) {
    // Set the A4 width
    this.style = {width: '29cm',height: '100%'};
    this.gridOptions.api.setDomLayout('print);
    // Remove focus cursor
    this.gridOptions.api.clearFocusedCell();
    // Print
    window.focus();
    window.print();
    // When the print popin closes :
    this.style = {width: '100%',height: '100%'};
}
```

I have add some media queries in my components to only display the grid on printing.

It works not so bad but I can't use ag-grid api method to set the layout in print mode and I don't understand why ?

---

Here the plunker I try to reproduce in my code https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview. Impossible to have the same behaviour in my code. I have tried the same lines :

```
const eGridDiv = document.querySelector('.grid-printable');
eGridDiv.style.width = '';
eGridDiv.style.height = '';
this.gridApi.setDomLayout('print');
```

but the following errors occurs :

```
ERROR in 
src/app/components/list/list.component.ts(190,14): error TS2339: Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element'.
src/app/dossiers/list/list.component.ts(191,14): error TS2339: Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element'.
```

and if I comment lines provoking these errors, I have the following javascript `error this.gridApi.setDomLayout is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

Might be cuz of it `setDomLayout('print);`- forgot one **quotation mark** (`'`), or its just bad copy-paste? If so - pls provide plnkr sample

Comment: on plnkr - to get direct link click 'save' or 'fork' and then post this link

Comment: so - this plnkr from the official demo, what I should get 'wrong' here?  Or what's wrong for you on this sample?

Answer (score 0):

Typecast your `eGridDiv` as:

```
const eGridDiv = document.querySelector('.grid-printable') as HTMLElement;
```

This will fix the Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element' error.